# Logo position changes when zooming out (CSS/Angular4+)

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, frontend

I have navbar which has a logo (MostafaOmar), and when I zoom out, the position moves as well.

Try zooming to 70%, and you will see the position of the logo moves as well.

How can I make it stay how it is when its at 100%?

[Logo](https://codepen.io/MustafaOmarIbrahim/pen/VKbQyZ)

```
.nav .nav-heading .brand {float: left}
```

Comment: lose the margin auto

Answer (score 1):

it looks like the re-sizing of the parent div with the class of `.container` is resizing and this is moving the contents, including your logo.

if you force the container class width to 80%, this fixes the problem for any resizes. your text might grow and shrink, but the location stays in the same place. I tested in your codepen and it works.

`.container {
width: 80%;
}`

alternatively, as you might not want to change the whole class, you could add an ID to the navbar container, and target the width of that the same way.

let me know if this helps

cheers